# Angular8 Material, Grid with both headers and tiles. mat-grid-tile content not totally resizing

Tags: typescript, angular-material, material-design, angular8

Angular8 Material, Grid with both headers and tiles.

I am trying to learn how the grid system works in Angular Material. I am dynamically pulling in the components into a grid.  Right now, the grid list and tiles work as expected. The rendering of the components (Autocompelete etc, also work as expected). But the content of the tiles is off. The mat-figure portion. It's like they aren't totally aware that they are inside of tiles.

For example, if the page shrinks, the grid tiles are responsive and resize, but the content within the tile, looks like it is over the containing. [image: over containing] Also the sizes (font's widths) do not shrink.    I could probably fix this with just CSS but I want to understand why the grid-list isn't working.

I attached some screenshots. One is of the grid with a small screen resolution, showing how the fonts don't shrink (isn't that part of Angular Material?) and the other is how its allenter image description here rendering in the console.[image: small resolution]

[image: Rendered HTML]

```js
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';

export interface ITile {
  color: string;
  cols: number;
  headerText: string;
  rows: number;
  text: string;
  componentName: string;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-forms',
  templateUrl: 'forms.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['forms.component.scss']
})
export class FormsComponent implements OnInit {
  tiles: Array<ITile>;

  setComponents() {
    this.tiles = new Array<ITile>();
    let components = [];
    components.push('autocomplete');
    components.push('checkbox');
    components.push('datepicker');
    components.push('formfield');
    components.push('input');
    components.push('radiobutton');
    components.push('select');
    components.push('slider');
    components.push('slidetoggle');
    console.log (components);

    components.forEach(component => {
      if (component === 'autocomplete') {
        const headerText = 'Auto Complete';
        this.setTile('#ccc', 4, headerText, 'example', 1, component);
      }
      if (component === 'checkbox') {
        const headerText = 'Checkbox';
        this.setTile('#ccc', 4, headerText, 'example', 1, component);
      }
      if (component === 'datepicker') {
        const headerText = 'Date Picker';
        this.setTile('#ccc', 4, headerText, 'example', 1, component);
      }
      if (component === 'formfield') {
        const headerText = 'Form Field';
        this.setTile('#ccc', 4, headerText, 'example', 1, component);
      }
      if (component === 'input') {
        const headerText = 'Input';
        this.setTile('#ccc', 4, headerText, 'example', 1, component);
      }
      if (component === 'radiobutton') {
        const headerText = 'Radio Button';
        this.setTile('#ccc', 4, headerText, 'example', 1, component);
      }
      if (component === 'select') {
        const headerText = 'Select';
        this.setTile('#ccc', 4, headerText, 'example', 1, component);
      }
      if (component === 'slider') {
        const headerText = 'Slider';
        this.setTile('#ccc', 4, headerText, 'example', 1, component);
      }
      if (component === 'slidetoggle') {
        const headerText = 'Slide Toggle';
        this.setTile('#ccc', 4, headerText, 'example', 1, component);
      }
    });
  }

  setTile(color: string, cols: number, headerText: string, text: string, rows: number, componentName: string) {
    const tile = {
      color,
      cols,
      headerText,
      text,
      rows,
      componentName
    };

    this.tiles.push(tile);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(this.tiles));
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
this.setComponents();
  }
}
```

```html
<mat-grid-list cols="4" rowHeight="1:1" gutterSize="55px">

  <mat-grid-tile class="grid-tile"
                 [colspan]="2"
                 [rowspan]="1"
                 *ngFor="let tile of tiles"
                 [colspan]="tile.cols"
                 [rowspan]="tile.rows"
                 [style.background]="tile.color">
    {{tile.text}}
    <app-checkbox *ngIf="tile.componentName === 'checkbox'"></app-checkbox>

    <app-autocomplete *ngIf="tile.componentName === 'autocomplete'"></app-autocomplete>
    <app-checkbox *ngIf="tile.componentName === 'checkbox'"></app-checkbox>

    <app-datepicker *ngIf="tile.componentName === 'datepicker'"></app-datepicker>
    <app-formfield *ngIf="tile.componentName === 'formfield'"></app-formfield>

    <app-input *ngIf="tile.componentName === 'input'"></app-input>
    <app-radiobutton *ngIf="tile.componentName ==='radiobutton'"></app-radiobutton>

    <app-select *ngIf="tile.componentName === 'select'"></app-select>
    <app-slider *ngIf="tile.componentName ==='slider'"></app-slider>

    <app-sidetoggle *ngIf="tile.componentName === 'slidetoggle'"></app-sidetoggle>
    <div style="width: 230px;"></div>

    <mat-grid-tile-header>
      <h3> {{tile.headerText}} </h3>
    </mat-grid-tile-header>
  </mat-grid-tile>
</mat-grid-list>
```

Comment: You know, looking at the docs, maybe content inside of a tile does not scale even though the tiles are made to be responsive themselves.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem. I ended up not using the material grid but angular flex grid.
https://tburleson-layouts-demos.firebaseapp.com/#/docs

Then you can use this layout grid:

```
  <div class="parent flex-card-height" fxLayout="row" fxLayout.sm="column" fxLayout.xs="column" fxLayoutGap="32px" fxFill>
    <mat-card fxFlex="50%" fxFill>
      <div class="mat-card-title heading"></div>
      <div class="left"
           *ngFor="let tile of tiles">
        {{tile.text}}
        <app-autocomplete *ngIf="tile.componentName === 'autocomplete'" class="spacing"></app-autocomplete>
      </div>
    </mat-card>

    <mat-card fxFlex="50%" fxFill>
      <div class="mat-card-title heading"></div>
      <div class="right"
           *ngFor="let tile of tiles">
        {{tile.text}}
        <app-checkbox *ngIf="tile.componentName === 'checkbox'" class="spacing"></app-checkbox>
      </div>
    </mat-card>
  </div>
```